# StarCraft II, Wine, Ironhide

Tags: wine, nvidia-optimus

ASUS N43JM notebook
NVIDIA Geforce GT 435M
Ubuntu 11.10 64bit
Switchable graphics, working through ironhide

Ironhide Settings:

- Automatic Shutdown of nVidia Card: NO
- Virtual Terminal: 8
- Image Transport: xv
- Read Back Mode: pbo
- Log File for VirtualGL: /dev/null
- Powersave/Economic Mode: NO
- Always Enable the nVidia card before disabling: YES

When I try to run StartCraft II using:

```
~$ optirun wine "C:/StarCraft2/StarCraft II.exe"
```

The game starts. The video lags, but the games runs kind of smooth if I have all of the graphics settings turns to the lowest. I'm wondering if I could get the graphics quality higher, and if there's something not working properly. It lags enough that it has trouble loading missions or even moving around to different screens sometimes. Hangs when shutting the game off.

I get this (some repeating commands were deleted to make room)

```
    * Starting Ironhide X server ironhide                                                                                                                 _PS0 Enabling nVidia Card Succeded.
.                                                                                                                                               [ OK ]
ERROR: ld.so: object 'libdlfaker.so' from LD_PRELOAD cannot be preloaded: ignored.
err:winediag:wined3d_dll_init The GLSL shader backend has been disabled. You get to keep all the pieces if it breaks.
fixme:process:GetLogicalProcessorInformation ((nil),0x32dca0): stub
fixme:win:EnumDisplayDevicesW ((null),0,0x107c2e4,0x00000000), stub!
fixme:ddraw:DirectDrawEnumerateExA flags 0x00000003 not handled
fixme:wininet:InternetSetOptionW Option INTERNET_OPTION_CONNECT_TIMEOUT (3000): STUB
fixme:wininet:InternetSetOptionW INTERNET_OPTION_SEND/RECEIVE_TIMEOUT/DATA_SEND_TIMEOUT 3000
fixme:wininet:InternetSetOptionW Option INTERNET_OPTION_CONNECT_TIMEOUT (2000): STUB
fixme:wininet:InternetSetOptionW INTERNET_OPTION_SEND/RECEIVE_TIMEOUT/DATA_SEND_TIMEOUT 2000
fixme:process:GetLogicalProcessorInformation ((nil),0x137c650): stub
fixme:process:GetLogicalProcessorInformation ((nil),0x137c63c): stub
fixme:wininet:URLCache_FindFirstFreeEntry Grow file
err:wininet:CommitUrlCacheEntryInternal no free entries
fixme:process:GetLogicalProcessorInformation ((nil),0x147e998): stub
fixme:wininet:CommitUrlCacheEntryInternal entry already in cache - don't know what to do!
fixme:process:GetLogicalProcessorInformation ((nil),0x147e998): stub
ERROR: ld.so: object 'libdlfaker.so' from LD_PRELOAD cannot be preloaded: ignored.
fixme:shell:SetCurrentProcessExplicitAppUserModelID L"BlizzardEntertainment.StarCraftII.StarCraftII": stub
ERROR: ld.so: object 'libdlfaker.so' from LD_PRELOAD cannot be preloaded: ignored.
shui@shui-N43JM:~$ err:winediag:wined3d_dll_init The GLSL shader backend has been disabled. You get to keep all the pieces if it breaks.
fixme:process:SetProcessDEPPolicy (1): stub
fixme:process:GetLogicalProcessorInformation (0x33fa3c,0x33fd3c): stub
fixme:hnetcfg:fw_profile_get_FirewallEnabled 0x174588, 0x461f0d4
fixme:process:GetProcessWorkingSetSize (0xffffffff,0x461ed40,0x461ed44): stub
fixme:ntdll:NtQuerySystemInformation info_class SYSTEM_PERFORMANCE_INFORMATION
fixme:win:EnumDisplayDevicesW ((null),0,0x461e9f4,0x00000000), stub!
fixme:win:EnumDisplayDevicesW ((null),0,0x461e908,0x00000000), stub!
fixme:d3d:debug_d3dformat Unrecognized 0x36314644 (as fourcc: DF16) WINED3DFORMAT!
fixme:d3d:wined3d_get_format Can't find format unrecognized (0x36314644) in the format lookup table
fixme:d3d:debug_d3dformat Unrecognized 0x36314644 (as fourcc: DF16) WINED3DFORMAT!
fixme:d3d:wined3d_get_format Can't find format unrecognized (0x36314644) in the format lookup table
fixme:d3d:debug_d3dformat Unrecognized 0x34324644 (as fourcc: DF24) WINED3DFORMAT!
fixme:d3d:wined3d_get_format Can't find format unrecognized (0x34324644) in the format lookup table
fixme:d3d:debug_d3dformat Unrecognized 0x34324644 (as fourcc: DF24) WINED3DFORMAT!
fixme:d3d:wined3d_get_format Can't find format unrecognized (0x34324644) in the format lookup table
fixme:win:EnumDisplayDevicesW ((null),0,0x461e7c0,0x00000000), stub!
fixme:win:EnumDisplayDevicesW ((null),0,0x461e798,0x00000000), stub!
fixme:d3d:resource_check_usage Unhandled usage flags 0x8.
fixme:thread:SetThreadIdealProcessor (0xfffffffe): stub
fixme:thread:SetThreadIdealProcessor (0xfffffffe): stub
fixme:thread:SetThreadIdealProcessor (0xfffffffe): stub
fixme:d3d:resource_check_usage Unhandled usage flags 0x8.
fixme:d3d:resource_check_usage Unhandled usage flags 0x8.
fixme:alsa:AudioClient_GetMixFormat Don't know what to do with 32 channels, pretending there's only 2 channels
fixme:alsa:AudioClient_GetMixFormat Don't know what to do with 10000 channels, pretending there's only 2 channels
fixme:avrt:AvSetMmThreadCharacteristicsW (L"Audio",0x869ea18): stub
fixme:d3d:resource_check_usage Unhandled usage flags 0x8.
fixme:d3d9:Direct3DShaderValidatorCreate9 stub
fixme:d3d:resource_check_usage Unhandled usage flags 0x8.
fixme:winhttp:WinHttpGetIEProxyConfigForCurrentUser returning no proxy used
err:d3d_surface:surface_allocate_surface >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> GL_INVALID_ENUM (0x500) from glCompressedTexImage2DARB @ surface.c / 2589
err:d3d_surface:surface_upload_data >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> GL_INVALID_ENUM (0x500) from glCompressedTexSubImage2DARB @ surface.c / 2481
fixme:winsock:WSAIoctl WS_SIO_UDP_CONNRESET stub
fixme:d3d:resource_check_usage Unhandled usage flags 0x8.
fixme:win:EnumDisplayDevicesW ((null),0,0x4612cb4,0x00000000), stub!
fixme:win:EnumDisplayDevicesW ((null),0,0x4612f84,0x00000000), stub!
fixme:win:EnumDisplayDevicesW ((null),0,0x4612f74,0x00000000), stub!
fixme:win:EnumDisplayDevicesW ((null),0,0x4612d08,0x00000000), stub!
fixme:alsa:AudioClient_GetMixFormat Don't know what to do with 32 channels, pretending there's only 2 channels
fixme:avrt:AvSetMmThreadCharacteristicsW (L"Audio",0x2575ea18): stub
fixme:d3d:resource_check_usage Unhandled usage flags 0x8.
fixme:winhttp:WinHttpGetIEProxyConfigForCurrentUser returning no proxy used
fixme:imm:ImmReleaseContext (0x50038, 0x17de90): stub
err:d3d_surface:surface_allocate_surface >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> GL_INVALID_ENUM (0x500) from glCompressedTexImage2DARB @ surface.c / 2589
err:d3d_surface:surface_allocate_surface >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> GL_INVALID_ENUM (0x500) from glCompressedTexImage2DARB @ surface.c / 2589
err:d3d_surface:surface_allocate_surface >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> GL_INVALID_ENUM (0x500) from glCompressedTexImage2DARB @ surface.c / 2589
err:d3d_surface:surface_allocate_surface >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> GL_INVALID_ENUM (0x500) from glCompressedTexImage2DARB @ surface.c / 2589
err:d3d_surface:surface_allocate_surface >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> GL_INVALID_ENUM (0x500) from glCompressedTexImage2DARB @ surface.c / 2589
err:d3d_surface:surface_allocate_surface >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> GL_INVALID_ENUM (0x500) from glCompressedTexImage2DARB @ surface.c / 2589
err:d3d_surface:surface_allocate_surface >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> GL_INVALID_ENUM (0x500) from glCompressedTexImage2DARB @ surface.c / 2589
err:d3d_surface:surface_allocate_surface >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> GL_INVALID_ENUM (0x500) from glCompressedTexImage2DARB @ surface.c / 2589
err:d3d_surface:surface_upload_data >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> GL_INVALID_ENUM (0x500) from glCompressedTexSubImage2DARB @ surface.c / 2481
err:d3d_surface:surface_upload_data >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> GL_INVALID_ENUM (0x500) from glCompressedTexSubImage2DARB @ surface.c / 2481
err:d3d_surface:surface_upload_data >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> GL_INVALID_ENUM (0x500) from glCompressedTexSubImage2DARB @ surface.c / 2481
err:d3d_surface:surface_upload_data >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> GL_INVALID_ENUM (0x500) from glCompressedTexSubImage2DARB @ surface.c / 2481
err:d3d_surface:surface_upload_data >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> GL_INVALID_ENUM (0x500) from glCompressedTexSubImage2DARB @ surface.c / 2481
err:d3d_surface:surface_upload_data >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> GL_INVALID_ENUM (0x500) from glCompressedTexSubImage2DARB @ surface.c / 2481
err:d3d_surface:surface_upload_data >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> GL_INVALID_ENUM (0x500) from glCompressedTexSubImage2DARB @ surface.c / 2481
err:d3d_surface:surface_upload_data >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> GL_INVALID_ENUM (0x500) from glCompressedTexSubImage2DARB @ surface.c / 2481
err:d3d_surface:surface_allocate_surface >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> GL_INVALID_ENUM (0x500) from glCompressedTexImage2DARB @ surface.c / 2589
err:d3d_surface:surface_allocate_surface >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> GL_INVALID_ENUM (0x500) from glCompressedTexImage2DARB @ surface.c / 2589
err:d3d_surface:surface_allocate_surface >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> GL_INVALID_ENUM (0x500) from glCompressedTexImage2DARB @ surface.c / 2589
err:d3d_surface:surface_allocate_surface >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> GL_INVALID_ENUM (0x500) from glCompressedTexImage2DARB @ surface.c / 2589
err:d3d_surface:surface_allocate_surface >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> GL_INVALID_ENUM (0x500) from glCompressedTexImage2DARB @ surface.c / 2589
err:d3d_surface:surface_allocate_surface >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> GL_INVALID_ENUM (0x500) from glCompressedTexImage2DARB @ surface.c / 2589
err:d3d_surface:surface_upload_data >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> GL_INVALID_ENUM (0x500) from glCompressedTexSubImage2DARB @ surface.c / 2481
err:d3d_surface:surface_upload_data >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> GL_INVALID_ENUM (0x500) from glCompressedTexSubImage2DARB @ surface.c / 2481
err:d3d_surface:surface_upload_data >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> GL_INVALID_ENUM (0x500) from glCompressedTexSubImage2DARB @ surface.c / 2481
err:d3d_surface:surface_upload_data >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> GL_INVALID_ENUM (0x500) from glCompressedTexSubImage2DARB @ surface.c / 2481
err:d3d_surface:surface_upload_data >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> GL_INVALID_ENUM (0x500) from glCompressedTexSubImage2DARB @ surface.c / 2481
err:d3d_surface:surface_upload_data >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> GL_INVALID_ENUM (0x500) from glCompressedTexSubImage2DARB @ surface.c / 2481
err:d3d_surface:surface_allocate_surface >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> GL_INVALID_ENUM (0x500) from glCompressedTexImage2DARB @ surface.c / 2589
err:d3d_surface:surface_allocate_surface >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> GL_INVALID_ENUM (0x500) from glCompressedTexImage2DARB @ surface.c / 2589
err:d3d_surface:surface_allocate_surface >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> GL_INVALID_ENUM (0x500) from glCompressedTexImage2DARB @ surface.c / 2589
err:d3d_surface:surface_allocate_surface >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> GL_INVALID_ENUM (0x500) from glCompressedTexImage2DARB @ surface.c / 2589
err:d3d_surface:surface_allocate_surface >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> GL_INVALID_ENUM (0x500) from glCompressedTexImage2DARB @ surface.c / 2589
err:d3d_surface:surface_allocate_surface >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> GL_INVALID_ENUM (0x500) from glCompressedTexImage2DARB @ surface.c / 2589
err:d3d_surface:surface_allocate_surface >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> GL_INVALID_ENUM (0x500) from glCompressedTexImage2DARB @ surface.c / 2589
err:d3d_surface:surface_allocate_surface >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> GL_INVALID_ENUM (0x500) from glCompressedTexImage2DARB @ surface.c / 2589
err:d3d_surface:surface_allocate_surface >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> GL_INVALID_ENUM (0x500) from glCompressedTexImage2DARB @ surface.c / 2589
err:d3d_surface:surface_upload_data >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> GL_INVALID_ENUM (0x500) from glCompressedTexSubImage2DARB @ surface.c / 2481
err:d3d_surface:surface_upload_data >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> GL_INVALID_ENUM (0x500) from glCompressedTexSubImage2DARB @ surface.c / 2481
err:d3d_surface:surface_upload_data >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> GL_INVALID_ENUM (0x500) from glCompressedTexSubImage2DARB @ surface.c / 2481
err:d3d_surface:surface_upload_data >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> GL_INVALID_ENUM (0x500) from glCompressedTexSubImage2DARB @ surface.c / 2481
err:d3d_surface:surface_upload_data >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> GL_INVALID_ENUM (0x500) from glCompressedTexSubImage2DARB @ surface.c / 2481
err:d3d_surface:surface_upload_data >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> GL_INVALID_ENUM (0x500) from glCompressedTexSubImage2DARB @ surface.c / 2481
err:d3d_surface:surface_upload_data >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> GL_INVALID_ENUM (0x500) from glCompressedTexSubImage2DARB @ surface.c / 2481
err:d3d_surface:surface_upload_data >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> GL_INVALID_ENUM (0x500) from glCompressedTexSubImage2DARB @ surface.c / 2481
err:d3d_surface:surface_upload_data >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> GL_INVALID_ENUM (0x500) from glCompressedTexSubImage2DARB @ surface.c / 2481
err:d3d_surface:surface_allocate_surface >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> GL_INVALID_ENUM (0x500) from glCompressedTexImage2DARB @ surface.c / 2589
err:d3d_surface:surface_allocate_surface >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> GL_INVALID_ENUM (0x500) from glCompressedTexImage2DARB @ surface.c / 2589
err:d3d_surface:surface_allocate_surface >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> GL_INVALID_ENUM (0x500) from glCompressedTexImage2DARB @ surface.c / 2589
err:d3d_surface:surface_allocate_surface >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> GL_INVALID_ENUM (0x500) from glCompressedTexImage2DARB @ surface.c / 2589
err:d3d_surface:surface_allocate_surface >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> GL_INVALID_ENUM (0x500) from glCompressedTexImage2DARB @ surface.c / 2589
err:d3d_surface:surface_allocate_surface >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> GL_INVALID_ENUM (0x500) from glCompressedTexImage2DARB @ surface.c / 2589
err:d3d_surface:surface_allocate_surface >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> GL_INVALID_ENUM (0x500) from glCompressedTexImage2DARB @ surface.c / 2589
err:d3d_surface:surface_upload_data >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> GL_INVALID_ENUM (0x500) from glCompressedTexSubImage2DARB @ surface.c / 2481
err:d3d_surface:surface_upload_data >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> GL_INVALID_ENUM (0x500) from glCompressedTexSubImage2DARB @ surface.c / 2481
err:d3d_surface:surface_upload_data >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> GL_INVALID_ENUM (0x500) from glCompressedTexSubImage2DARB @ surface.c / 2481
err:d3d_surface:surface_upload_data >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> GL_INVALID_ENUM (0x500) from glCompressedTexSubImage2DARB @ surface.c / 2481
err:d3d_surface:surface_upload_data >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> GL_INVALID_ENUM (0x500) from glCompressedTexSubImage2DARB @ surface.c / 2481
err:d3d_surface:surface_upload_data >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> GL_INVALID_ENUM (0x500) from glCompressedTexSubImage2DARB @ surface.c / 2481
err:d3d_surface:surface_upload_data >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> GL_INVALID_ENUM (0x500) from glCompressedTexSubImage2DARB @ surface.c / 2481
err:d3d_surface:surface_allocate_surface >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> GL_INVALID_ENUM (0x500) from glCompressedTexImage2DARB @ surface.c / 2589
err:d3d_surface:surface_allocate_surface >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> GL_INVALID_ENUM (0x500) from glCompressedTexImage2DARB @ surface.c / 2589
err:d3d_surface:surface_allocate_surface >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> GL_INVALID_ENUM (0x500) from glCompressedTexImage2DARB @ surface.c / 2589
err:d3d_surface:surface_allocate_surface >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> GL_INVALID_ENUM (0x500) from glCompressedTexImage2DARB @ surface.c / 2589
err:d3d_surface:surface_allocate_surface >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> GL_INVALID_ENUM (0x500) from glCompressedTexImage2DARB @ surface.c / 2589
err:d3d_surface:surface_allocate_surface >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> GL_INVALID_ENUM (0x500) from glCompressedTexImage2DARB @ surface.c / 2589
err:d3d_surface:surface_allocate_surface >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> GL_INVALID_ENUM (0x500) from glCompressedTexImage2DARB @ surface.c / 2589
err:d3d_surface:surface_upload_data >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> GL_INVALID_ENUM (0x500) from glCompressedTexSubImage2DARB @ surface.c / 2481
err:d3d_surface:surface_upload_data >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> GL_INVALID_ENUM (0x500) from glCompressedTexSubImage2DARB @ surface.c / 2481
err:d3d_surface:surface_upload_data >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> GL_INVALID_ENUM (0x500) from glCompressedTexSubImage2DARB @ surface.c / 2481
err:d3d_surface:surface_upload_data >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> GL_INVALID_ENUM (0x500) from glCompressedTexSubImage2DARB @ surface.c / 2481
err:d3d_surface:surface_upload_data >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> GL_INVALID_ENUM (0x500) from glCompressedTexSubImage2DARB @ surface.c / 2481
err:d3d_surface:surface_upload_data >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> GL_INVALID_ENUM (0x500) from glCompressedTexSubImage2DARB @ surface.c / 2481
err:d3d_surface:surface_upload_data >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> GL_INVALID_ENUM (0x500) from glCompressedTexSubImage2DARB @ surface.c / 2481
err:d3d_surface:surface_allocate_surface >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> GL_INVALID_ENUM (0x500) from glCompressedTexImage2DARB @ surface.c / 2589
err:d3d_surface:surface_allocate_surface >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> GL_INVALID_ENUM (0x500) from glCompressedTexImage2DARB @ surface.c / 2589
err:d3d_surface:surface_allocate_surface >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> GL_INVALID_ENUM (0x500) from glCompressedTexImage2DARB @ surface.c / 2589
err:d3d_surface:surface_allocate_surface >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> GL_INVALID_ENUM (0x500) from glCompressedTexImage2DARB @ surface.c / 2589
err:d3d_surface:surface_allocate_surface >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> GL_INVALID_ENUM (0x500) from glCompressedTexImage2DARB @ surface.c / 2589
err:d3d_surface:surface_allocate_surface >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> GL_INVALID_ENUM (0x500) from glCompressedTexImage2DARB @ surface.c / 2589
err:d3d_surface:surface_allocate_surface >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> GL_INVALID_ENUM (0x500) from glCompressedTexImage2DARB @ surface.c / 2589
err:d3d_surface:surface_upload_data >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> GL_INVALID_ENUM (0x500) from glCompressedTexSubImage2DARB @ surface.c / 2481
err:d3d_surface:surface_upload_data >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> GL_INVALID_ENUM (0x500) from glCompressedTexSubImage2DARB @ surface.c / 2481
err:d3d_surface:surface_upload_data >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> GL_INVALID_ENUM (0x500) from glCompressedTexSubImage2DARB @ surface.c / 2481
err:d3d_surface:surface_upload_data >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> GL_INVALID_ENUM (0x500) from glCompressedTexSubImage2DARB @ surface.c / 2481
err:d3d_surface:surface_upload_data >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> GL_INVALID_ENUM (0x500) from glCompressedTexSubImage2DARB @ surface.c / 2481
err:d3d_surface:surface_upload_data >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> GL_INVALID_ENUM (0x500) from glCompressedTexSubImage2DARB @ surface.c / 2481
err:d3d_surface:surface_upload_data >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> GL_INVALID_ENUM (0x500) from glCompressedTexSubImage2DARB @ surface.c / 2481
err:d3d_surface:surface_allocate_surface >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> GL_INVALID_ENUM (0x500) from glCompressedTexImage2DARB @ surface.c / 2589
err:d3d_surface:surface_allocate_surface >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> GL_INVALID_ENUM (0x500) from glCompressedTexImage2DARB @ surface.c / 2589
err:d3d_surface:surface_allocate_surface >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> GL_INVALID_ENUM (0x500) from glCompressedTexImage2DARB @ surface.c / 2589
err:d3d_surface:surface_allocate_surface >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> GL_INVALID_ENUM (0x500) from glCompressedTexImage2DARB @ surface.c / 2589
err:d3d_surface:surface_allocate_surface >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> GL_INVALID_ENUM (0x500) from glCompressedTexImage2DARB @ surface.c / 2589
err:d3d_surface:surface_allocate_surface >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> GL_INVALID_ENUM (0x500) from glCompressedTexImage2DARB @ surface.c / 2589
err:d3d_surface:surface_allocate_surface >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> GL_INVALID_ENUM (0x500) from glCompressedTexImage2DARB @ surface.c / 2589
err:d3d_surface:surface_upload_data >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> GL_INVALID_ENUM (0x500) from glCompressedTexSubImage2DARB @ surface.c / 2481
err:d3d_surface:surface_upload_data >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> GL_INVALID_ENUM (0x500) from glCompressedTexSubImage2DARB @ surface.c / 2481
err:d3d_surface:surface_upload_data >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> GL_INVALID_ENUM (0x500) from glCompressedTexSubImage2DARB @ surface.c / 2481
err:d3d_surface:surface_upload_data >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> GL_INVALID_ENUM (0x500) from glCompressedTexSubImage2DARB @ surface.c / 2481
err:d3d_surface:surface_upload_data >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> GL_INVALID_ENUM (0x500) from glCompressedTexSubImage2DARB @ surface.c / 2481
err:d3d_surface:surface_upload_data >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> GL_INVALID_ENUM (0x500) from glCompressedTexSubImage2DARB @ surface.c / 2481
err:d3d_surface:surface_upload_data >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> GL_INVALID_ENUM (0x500) from glCompressedTexSubImage2DARB @ surface.c / 2481
err:d3d_surface:surface_allocate_surface >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> GL_INVALID_ENUM (0x500) from glCompressedTexImage2DARB @ surface.c / 2589
err:d3d_surface:surface_allocate_surface >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> GL_INVALID_ENUM (0x500) from glCompressedTexImage2DARB @ surface.c / 2589
err:d3d_surface:surface_allocate_surface >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> GL_INVALID_ENUM (0x500) from glCompressedTexImage2DARB @ surface.c / 2589
err:d3d_surface:surface_allocate_surface >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> GL_INVALID_ENUM (0x500) from glCompressedTexImage2DARB @ surface.c / 2589
err:d3d_surface:surface_allocate_surface >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> GL_INVALID_ENUM (0x500) from glCompressedTexImage2DARB @ surface.c / 2589
err:d3d_surface:surface_allocate_surface >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> GL_INVALID_ENUM (0x500) from glCompressedTexImage2DARB @ surface.c / 2589
err:d3d_surface:surface_upload_data >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> GL_INVALID_ENUM (0x500) from glCompressedTexSubImage2DARB @ surface.c / 2481
err:d3d_surface:surface_upload_data >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> GL_INVALID_ENUM (0x500) from glCompressedTexSubImage2DARB @ surface.c / 2481
err:d3d_surface:surface_upload_data >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> GL_INVALID_ENUM (0x500) from glCompressedTexSubImage2DARB @ surface.c / 2481
err:d3d_surface:surface_upload_data >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> GL_INVALID_ENUM (0x500) from glCompressedTexSubImage2DARB @ surface.c / 2481
err:d3d_surface:surface_upload_data >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> GL_INVALID_ENUM (0x500) from glCompressedTexSubImage2DARB @ surface.c / 2481
err:d3d_surface:surface_upload_data >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> GL_INVALID_ENUM (0x500) from glCompressedTexSubImage2DARB @ surface.c / 2481
fixme:d3d:resource_check_usage Unhandled usage flags 0x8.
fixme:d3d:resource_check_usage Unhandled usage flags 0x8.
fixme:win:EnumDisplayDevicesW ((null),0,0x46150f0,0x00000000), stub!
fixme:win:EnumDisplayDevicesW ((null),0,0x4614f68,0x00000000), stub!
fixme:win:EnumDisplayDevicesW ((null),0,0x46150e0,0x00000000), stub!
fixme:win:EnumDisplayDevicesW ((null),0,0x4614e74,0x00000000), stub!
fixme:alsa:AudioClient_GetMixFormat Don't know what to do with 32 channels, pretending there's only 2 channels
fixme:avrt:AvSetMmThreadCharacteristicsW (L"Audio",0xc9eea18): stub
err:d3d_surface:surface_allocate_surface >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> GL_INVALID_ENUM (0x500) from glCompressedTexImage2DARB @ surface.c / 2589
err:d3d_surface:surface_upload_data >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> GL_INVALID_ENUM (0x500) from glCompressedTexSubImage2DARB @ surface.c / 2481
fixme:winhttp:WinHttpGetIEProxyConfigForCurrentUser returning no proxy used
err:d3d_surface:surface_allocate_surface >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> GL_INVALID_ENUM (0x500) from glCompressedTexImage2DARB @ surface.c / 2589
err:d3d_surface:surface_upload_data >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> GL_INVALID_ENUM (0x500) from glCompressedTexSubImage2DARB @ surface.c / 2481
err:d3d_surface:surface_allocate_surface >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> GL_INVALID_ENUM (0x500) from glCompressedTexImage2DARB @ surface.c / 2589
err:d3d_surface:surface_upload_data >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> GL_INVALID_ENUM (0x500) from glCompressedTexSubImage2DARB @ surface.c / 2481
fixme:winhttp:WinHttpGetIEProxyConfigForCurrentUser returning no proxy used
err:d3d_surface:surface_allocate_surface >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> GL_INVALID_ENUM (0x500) from glCompressedTexImage2DARB @ surface.c / 2589
err:d3d_surface:surface_upload_data >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> GL_INVALID_ENUM (0x500) from glCompressedTexSubImage2DARB @ surface.c / 2481
err:d3d_surface:surface_allocate_surface >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> GL_INVALID_ENUM (0x500) from glCompressedTexImage2DARB @ surface.c / 2589
err:d3d_surface:surface_upload_data >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> GL_INVALID_ENUM (0x500) from glCompressedTexSubImage2DARB @ surface.c / 2481
```

Comment: Does the game work? What's the problem?

Comment: No one has any suggestions to improve graphic performance in wine? :(

Comment: it could be your computer! is it faster in windows?

Comment: Wine has several open bugs with this game http://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=version&iId=20882 is impossible to address them all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately StarCraft II is currently unplayable with Wine (even on 1.3.31). It wouldn't change no matter how powerfull your computer was. You would still have to run it on the lowest graphic settings and the fps would be often dropping to 15 frames or even less.

[WineHQ AppDB page for StarCraft II](http://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=version&iId=20882) you will find there test results for that game, tips and comments of other people.

Comment: In the comments to those tests you will see that it is mostly unplayable especially if you want to play it in multiplayer. Than you have a section of comments mostly in regards to how to get better performance. Those workarounds doesn't solve that problem. The game uses just one core of the processor and it is highly dependant on that (just look at Windows benchmarks).

Comment: Look man, I do nothing else other than play multiplayer maps lately, my graphics card was bought 2 years ago and even using 1 core from my 4 at 3.2Ghz (only) the game is playable at medium settings and the network connection is more stable than in Windows (yes I also do use it). Its not perfect and it will not be for everyone but its really far from what you state here, I have been playing it with this config since it was released both in Windows and Linux without major issues. If you excuse me I will purge the comments above cause this conversation is getting too big for comments.

Answer (score 5):

I am running Starcraft II with almost everything set to maximum with a GeForce 8800 GT using wine 1.3.25, which seems to be the currently most recommendable wine-version for newer Blizzard games. Everything is running nicely.

This is on a normal PC though, without Ironhide of course. However, this might help to get the right wine versions to test.

Answer (score 1):

If you have 32-bit applications like Wine, and run 11.10 Oneiric or later, you will need extra libraries:

```
sudo apt-get install virtualgl-libs:i386
```

[Is a NVIDIA GeForce with Optimus Technology supported by Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/36930/how-well-do-laptops-with-nvidia-optimus-work)